# How to manage PagingToolbar in Ext-js 4.2 correctly?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, paging, toolbar

js 4.2), and I've got some problems when I manage a toolbar on  a grid which use a Proxy (ajax).

```
 this.grid  = new Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
            region      : 'center',
            loadMask    : true,
            layout      : 'fit',
            store       : 'Contenedores',

            tbar: [
                   { text: 'Exportar Excel' },
                   '->',
                   { text:'Buscar',     handler: this.buscar,   scope: this},
                   '-',
                   { text:'Limpiar',    handler: this.limpiar,  scope: this}
            ],
            columns : [],

            bbar : new Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging',{
                store: 'Contenedores', displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg  : 'Registros {0} - {1} de {2}',
                emptyMsg    : 'No hay registros'
            })
        });
```

The problems, I'm having are:

- When I call to store.load(), pagingToolbar doesn't block so I can click on the next page, and when the grid is loaded I get the incorrect page on pagingtoolbar. On Ext js 3 when I se loadMask: true on the grid, the pagingToolbar gets locked when I call store.load().
- If I'm on a page like 2 or higher and I call to store.load(), pagingToolbar doesn't update, after loading, the current page label to 1.
- I need to implement a clean/reset button, so how can I clean the labels on the pagingtoolbar.

thanks in advance.

Comment: did the answer work for you?  If so, please mark as answered or provide reason why it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need to call store.load(*with paramethers*), and I found for myself that I can do it with: this.grid.store.loadPage(1,{params: {..}}), but I still need to find a way to clear the pagingtoolbar when I use my clean/resert button (point 3). thanks again for your help :D

Comment: updated answer to show example of setting params on store's proxy before calling moveFirst() on paging toolbar

Answer (score 2):

If an expected result of doing a `store.load()` is to go the the first page in your grid, you can simply call `moveFirst()` on your paging toolbar, rather than loading on the store directly.  Example:

```
var pagingtb = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging',{
                store: 'Contenedores', 
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg  : 'Registros {0} - {1} de {2}',
                emptyMsg    : 'No hay registros'
            });

this.grid  = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
            region      : 'center',
            loadMask    : true,
            layout      : 'fit',
            store       : 'Contenedores',

            tbar: [
                   { text: 'Exportar Excel' },
                   '->',
                   { text:'Buscar',     handler: this.buscar,   scope: this},
                   '-',
                   { text:'Limpiar',    handler: this.limpiar,  scope: this}
            ],
            columns : [],

            bbar : pagingtb 
        });

pagingtb.moveFirst();
```

Also, you don't need the keyword `new` before `Ext.create(...)` --> `create()` returns an instance of the specified class.

If you need your store to send extra parameters, you can set them on the proxy before calling `moveFirst()` or `doRefresh()` on your toolbar.  Example:

```
store.getProxy().extraParams.someParameter1 = 'some value';
store.getProxy().extraParams.someParameter2 = 'another value';
pagingtb.doRefresh(); // or .moveFirst() if you want the grid to 
                      // move to the first page after load
```

Comment: Thanks this solved a different issue for me which was "extjs pagingtoolbar next button not working" I had to call this moveFirst to get it to realize it was on the first page, maybe there is an easier way but it worked for me, thanks